# Pretty Printing Syntax Tree with Operator Precedence and Associativity in Haskell

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, pretty-print

Is there any commonly used method or even a library for pretty printing (and parsing) a syntax tree with (binary) operators that have an associativity and a precedence level assigned, so that the result uses as few brackets as possible?

---

Take the formulas of propositional calculus as an example:

```
data Formula
    = Atom String
    | Not (Formula)
    | And (Formula) (Formula)
    | Or (Formula) (Formula)
    | Imp (Formula) (Formula)
```

Assume that the precedence is `Imp` < `Or` < `And` < `Not` (so `Not` binds the most) and that `And`, `Or` and `Imp` should associate to the right; so for example `Imp (And (Imp (Atom "A") (Atom "B")) (Atom "A")) (Atom "B")` should print something like `(A -> B) /\ A -> B`.

---

Of course this could be achieved by pattern matching but this is tedious and very unpleasant; I'm looking for something similarly simple to this notation from the Coq proof assistant:

```
Notation "A /\ B" := (and A B) (at level 80, right associativity).
```

which generates a parser and a pretty printer.

Comment: There is no such language feature in Haskell as there is Coq - you are likely stuck writing a parser yourself. The standard [parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Expr.html) can handle this use case quite easily. [Some](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/boomerang-1.4.5.1) [libraries](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/invertible-syntax) allow you to define both a parser and pretty printer from some specification of the grammar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Show` instance for `Formula` might look like this:

```
instance Show Formula where
  showsPrec _ (Atom name) = showString name
  showsPrec p (Not formula) = showParen (p > 3) $
    showString "\\+ " . showsPrec 3 formula
  showsPrec p (And lhs rhs) = showParen (p > 2) $
    showsPrec 3 lhs . showString " /\\ " . showsPrec 2 rhs
  showsPrec p (Or lhs rhs) = showParen (p > 1) $
    showsPrec 2 lhs . showString " \\/ " . showsPrec 1 rhs
  showsPrec p (Imp lhs rhs) = showParen (p > 0) $
    showsPrec 1 lhs . showString " -> " . showsPrec 0 rhs
```

Which will allow any `Formula` to be `show`n with appropriate parens:

```
main = print $ Imp (And (Imp (Atom "A") (Atom "B")) (Atom "A")) (Atom "B")
```

Prints (`print` is `putStrLn . show`):

```
(A -> B) /\ A -> B
```